# ssh: Could not resolve hostname.......temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: linux, windows

My Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) was upgraded to WSL2 recently. When I type `wsl -l -v` in the PowerShell terminal, the following is displayed:

```
 NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
```

However, I receive the following error when trying to connect to the server using WSL2 terminal: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname fdr1: Temporary failure in name resolution.` With git bash or PowerShell terminal, it works fine, but not with WSL2. What could be the issue? I use ssh adr@frd1 to access the server although not working this time with WSL terminal. I would appreciate it if someone could direct me to a solution.
Thank you!
adr

Comment: Can you specify which server you mean? I guess you are using WSL2 to connect to an outside server, right? Or are you trying to connect to an SSH server inside WSL2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to Windows subsystem for Linux from another machine within network?](https://superuser.com/questions/1717753/how-to-connect-to-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-another-machine-within-networ)

Comment: @Celesteaka.73chn0 I want to connect to Ubuntu remote server using SSH inside WSL2 terminal.

Comment: Was this issues resolved, I am facing a similar issue, could not resolve hostname from Dev container, but it works from Host machine