# SSH into WSL2 from another machine outside local network

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hadoop

I'm trying to deploy a distributed systems hadoop framework project. Thus, I downloaded and installed WSL2 on my personal PC and created 2VMs as Linux Servers. Now, I need to SSH into the master node (personal pc) from the slave nodes (VM A has a public IP and VM B has only a local ip) to enstablish a connection. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  I think you'll find that this has the information you're looking for -- [How to connect to Windows subsystem for Linux from another machine within network?](https://superuser.com/questions/1717753/how-to-connect-to-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-another-machine-within-networ).  If that solves it for you, there should be a confirmation button in the header for you.  If that doesn't solve it, edit your question to add any additional details - Thanks!