# Accessing a WSL 2 distribution from your local area network (LAN)

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have a Windows 10 machine with WSL2 (running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) and a Linux machine in the LAN of the Windows machine.  I'm able to connect from the Windows host to the SSH server running in WSL.  Now I want to connect to the WSL from the Linux machine or to the Linux machine from the WSL. Now according to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1717756/1679186) I ran the following command in PowerShell on my Windows system:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=4000 connectaddress=192.168.101.100
```

where `192.168.101.100` is the IP of the WSL. Then how do I SSH from the Linux machine directly to WSL? I tried `ssh -p 4000 windowsHost@windowsAdress` but it is not working:

```
#ssh -vvv -p 4000 windowsHost@windowsAdress
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u8, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to windowsAdress [windowsAdress] port 4000.
```

... and it is stuck there.

Comment: I believe the firewall on the WSL host is blocking access to vEthernet(WSL) network device

Answer (score 2):

In your [other question](https://superuser.com/q/1758097/1210833), you show your  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with the SSH server running on the default port of 22.  If this is the case, then you will need to adjust your port forwarding `connectport` to:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=22 connectaddress=192.168.101.100
```

This will forward connections from port 4000 on the Windows host to port 22 on the WSL2 host.

You may also need a firewall rule, as mentioned in the comments.  However, you *should* typically receive a request from Windows Defender Firewall to allow the connection the first time you use it.

Keep in mind that you will have to adjust the `connectaddress` each time you reboot (or WSL2 restarts) because the IP address is dynamically assigned.  It's also good practice to delete the old port-forwarding rules each time. For this reason, I find it easier to use SSH itself to handle the port forwarding.  I won't repeat all the steps here, but you can find the details in ["Option 2" of this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403545/1165986).

Comment: thank you! I will try as soon as I access to the windows machine